# No esta llegando los datos mandados desde mi aplicación al backend de NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, ionic, express

Estoy tratando de mandar datos desde mi aplicación de Ionic/Angular a un servidor Back-End que se encargara de guardar los datos, estoy ejecutando un POST desde la app, pero en el back end, dice que no le esta llegando ninguna información de la APP.

Ionic/Angular service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, HttpOptions } from '@capacitor-community/http';
import { HTTP_OPTIONS, URL_SERVICIOS, HTTP_OPTIONS_NATIVE } from 'src/app/shared/commons/config';
import { 
  GetStockByCategoryDTO,
  GetCategoryDTO,
  RegisterStockDTO,
  GetProductByProductDTO,
  UpdateStockDTO
} from 'src/app/dtos/dtos.module';

const http = Http;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreService {

  store: string = `${URL_SERVICIOS}store/`

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }
  
  public registerStock = (form: RegisterStockDTO) => 
http.post(`${this.store}registerStock`, form, HTTP_OPTIONS)
    {
       const options: HttpOptions = {
          url: `${this.store}registerStock`,
          headers: HTTP_OPTIONS_NATIVE,
          data: form
        };
        console.log(options)
        return http.post(options);
    }

}
```

El console.log me regresa el JSON con todos los datos correctamente, pero en el back end, simplemente, me muestra un JSON vacio

```
app.post('/registerStock', (req, res: Object) => {
   console.log(req.body) // -> Me regresa un JSON vacio
});
```

Me esta mandando los headers, pero el body, no me lo manda como debe ser

En mi app.js, tengo esta configuración

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: ¿Tienes añadido el parser para el cuerpo de la solicitud en Express?

Comment: @MauricioContreras no es la misma pregunta del otro día?

Comment: @Legna Parece, pero no puedo enlazar a la misma hasta que la respuesta tenga al menos un upvote o sea  aceptada. :(

Comment: Actualizare la pregunta